Centering a ggplot graph in a Word Document using officer package in R
I am using the officer package to find and replace text in a template to make a report that will always have the same format.
In my function I use the following code to find the merge field, add in the ggplot I've created, and then remove the merge field:
# insert summary graphic
  df <- cursor_reach(df, "%graphinsert%")
  df <- body_add_gg(df,
                    parish_graph,
                    width = 6,
                    height = 5)
  
  df <- body_replace_all_text(df,
                              old_value = "%graphinsert%",
                              new_value = "")

The merge field itself is already center aligned in the template, but every time I run my function and it adds in the graph, it makes it left aligned. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Welcome to SO. Try adding this argument to body_add_gg():  style = "centered"

Welcome! Good question! Maybe adding a screenshot (with hand-drawn red lines <- meme) would make it a bit clearer. Also, @DavoOz: If you have an answer, you can post it as an answer.

@DavoOZ I've tried adding style = "centered" to the body_add_gg(), but I get the following error:
Error: could not match any style named 'centered' in c('Normal', 'heading 1', 'heading 2', 'heading 3', 'heading 4', 'heading 5', 'heading 6', 'heading 7', 'heading 8', 'heading 9', 'Subtitle', 'Title', 'Quote', 'List Paragraph', 'Intense Quote', 'header', 'footer')

From my understanding officer has no option to simply center align a ggplot. But you can achieve your desired result by passing an appropriate style=, which however requires that your template provides such a style. This said, using style = "centered" as suggested in the comments will only work for the default template shipped with officer which provides a "centered". That's the reason why you get an error, as apparently your template does not provide a "centered" style.
Hence, one option to fix that would be to add such a style to your template or use officer::docx_set_paragraph_style as I do below. A second option would be to add your ggplot via body_add_fpar and external_img which however requires to first export your plot to a temporary file. For both cases note that removing your placeholder text is not necessary when you set pos = "on" which will automatically remove any content at the cursor position.
While the reprex below is based on the default officer template it should also work with a custom template (I tested with my company template).
As a first step I create a docx with a placeholder text which should be replaced with a plot:
library(officer)

doc <- read_docx()

doc <- body_add_fpar(
  doc,
  fpar(
    "%graphinsert%",
    fp_p = fp_par(text.align = "center")
  )
)

print(doc, "my-doc.docx")

# Option 1: Add a centered style
df <- read_docx("my-doc.docx")

df <- cursor_reach(df, "%graphinsert%")

df <- docx_set_paragraph_style(
  df,
  style_id = "center",
  style_name = "center",
  fp_p = fp_par(text.align = "center")
)

df <- body_add_gg(
  df,
  ggplot2::ggplot(),
  style = "center",
  width = 3,
  height = 2.5,
  pos = "on"
)

print(df, "centered-gg.docx")

# Option 2: Use body_add_fpar and external_img
df <- read_docx("my-doc.docx")

df <- cursor_reach(df, "%graphinsert%")

file <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
ragg::agg_png(filename = file, width = 3, height = 2.5, units = "in")
print(ggplot2::ggplot())
dev.off()

df <- body_add_fpar(
  df,
  fpar(
    external_img(src = file, width = 3, height = 2.5),
    fp_p = fp_par(text.align = "center")
  ),
  pos = "on"
)

print(df, "centered-gg-2.docx")

For both options the result the output looks like so:

